# Couldn't resolve Mac error on VS2022 .NET MAUI

Tags: maui, macos-catalina, remote-login

I have setup macOS on virtual box. Remote login is enabled on mac see below image

[macRemotelogin image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeAY0.png)

But when I try to add this Mac machine in to pair it in my MAUI app I get below error:

[VS2022 Pair to Mac error Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHrMu.png)

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried using IP address as well as name of the machine.

Comment: Please do not post errors as images

Comment: Do you have your Mac on wirelss? If possible use a wired connection.

Comment: @PeterWessberg WiFi works just as well, I do it all the time. As long as the devices are on the same network... The VirtualBox might be a problem, it could be that there is some proxy or tunneling going on that prevents a connection.

Comment: I missed that it was on a Virutal Box.